# Breaking into list and assigning list item in one step

Tags: python, string, list, assign

I'm trying to change the contents of list created by using `list` on a string in one step. For instance, in the example below, I'd like to change the third item (*text* to *teat*) right after splitting the string in one step.

I.e. Suppose I'm trying to change the third item in a list created by using `list` on the string *text*.

So

```
result= list("text")[2] = "a"
```

gives me

```
>>> result
'a'
```

I was thinking this might work, but it doesn't:

```
result= (list("text")[2] = "a")
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I can achieve the desired result like so:

```
result=list("text")
result[2]= "a"
```

which gives me:

```
>>> result
['t', 'e', 'a', 't']
```

- Is there a one-liner which gives me the result I'm looking for?
- Why do the two attempts I listed not work? What is the Python principle I should read up on that keeps me from doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a one liner, this will work:

```
result = "text"[:2]+'a'+"text"[3:]

result
Out[583]: 'teat'
```

The reason your method did not work is nothing returns when you assign a value to a variable. i.e

```
list("text")[2] = "a"
```

returns nothing which you then try to assign to result.

Comment: No, `"a"` gets assigned to `result`

Comment: In this case result= list("text")[2] = "a", Yes, "a" is assigned to result because it's a chained assignment. However in this case result= (list("text")[2] = "a"), "a" is not assigned to result because due to the parenthesis, OP is trying to assign the return value of (list("text")[2] = "a") which is nothing to result, which caused the error.

Comment: I missed that you had dropped the `result = ` from the left-hand side... not reading carefully

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest defining a function, then calling it afterwards would a one-liner(for the most clean code). like,

```
def replace_character(text, ind, letter):
    text_list = list(text)
    text_list[ind] = letter
    return text_list
```

But if you looking for a strict one-liner, Allen's solution is good. Here is another one using **list comprehension**.

```
result = [letter if ind != 2 else "a" for ind, letter in enumerate(list("text"))]
# This basically does,
# Create a list using the characters of list("text")
# if the index of the character is 2, put "a" instead of character
print result
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple simple-satements seperated by semi-colons on the same line. So here's a one-liner:

```
>>> result = list('text'); result[2] = 'z'
>>> result
['t', 'e', 'z', 't']
>>>
```

There is no need for a one-liner though, and multiple statements on the same line are [officially discouraged](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations)

This construction:

```
result= list("text")[2] = "a"
```

Doesn't work because it is chained assignment, so it assigns `"a"` to `result` and to `list("text")[2]`. But the latter assignment doesn't matter because the list is never assigned to anything, and gets discarded.

Fundamentally, the root of your misunderstanding is that in Python, assignment is *not* an expression: it doesn't evaluate to anything, so it doesn't produce a value you can assign to. In C, for example, assignment *is* a statement and evaluates to the left-hand side of the assignment, so:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  int a;
  printf("%d", a = 10);
  return 0;
}
```

Gives the following output:

```
10
```

But in Python, it is not an expression, hence why it gave a SyntaxError when you put parentheses around it and tried to assign that to something else.